# How do I boost start?

Tags: burnout-paradise

My cars start races with no wheel spin, and accelerates very slowly. The enemy cars always dash ahead and I'm left in last place, until I manage to catch up.

Is this expected, or can I somehow boost my start to match other cars? I've tried holding the throttle earlier, spinning the wheels (throttle + brake), but my keys seem to be ignored before the green light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As the countdown starts, tap the brakes and immediately apply the throttle.
>   This should make the wheels spin and make the car do a "real-life" burnout, if this doesn't happen, try again until you succeed.
>   When the countdown gets to 1, release the throttle and then reapply it immediately.
>   You should hear your Boost ignite as you reapply the throttle. If not, you have failed to perform a Boost Start and must restart an event if you wish to do so.

From the Burnout wiki

Comment: Tried that, but saw no action at any point. Maybe I'm doing wrong, or that tip is just not for the Paraside game: `It first appeared in Burnout 2: Point of Impact and later on in Burnout 3: Takedown and Burnout Revenge (for Crash events only). ` Maybe it goes by another name nowadays, or is simply not there.